# renaming a bunch of files in bash

Tags: bash

I have a few files in linux:

```
_foo_1.php
_foo_2.php
_foo_3.php
```

I want to rename them all from _foo to _bar, preserving the rest of the filename.

I have tried this, but it doesn't rename anything:

```
rename 's/_foo/_bar/' *.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you're using is for Debian rename. Red Hat rename uses a completely different syntax.

```
rename _foo _bar _foo*.php
```